# No Longer Able to Access Spreadsheet Via URL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The below code used to work perfectly to get a range from one spreadsheet and use them as the values for a range in another spreadsheet.  It will no longer work.   I have tried openByUrl functions in other scripts and they will not execute, either.  Error message that debugging gives me is that openByUrl cannot be found in object SpreadsheetApp.  Any idea why?

```
function IMtasks(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/##############/edit#gid=#########');
var tasks = tss.getSheetByName("TASKS");
var tasksrange = tasks.getRange("A3:F102").getValues();
sheet.getRange("A202:F301").setValues(tasksrange);

}
```

Comment: I prefer `.openById()` which you would pass your first set of #### characters.  When I use the `.openByUrl` I end the url at _/edit_  I prefer this because I have seen the url change for the G Suite accounts but the ID has been consistent.

Comment: I should have included in original post that I have tried openByID and have the same issue.  Thanks for the input, though.

Comment: Quote the error message

Comment: @TheMaster Ran that script again. Got no error message but no results. Ran the script below and it returned the following error:  "Invalid argument: url (line 5, file "Code"
    function getParentFolder(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var vals = ss.getSheetByName("VALUES");
    var driveFile = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://drive.google.com/open? id=#####"); 
    var parentFolder = driveFile.getParents();
    while (parentFolder.hasNext()) {
    var folder = parentFolder.next();
    var title = folder.getName();
    }